# FancyBox Custom Close Button Border-Radius Issue

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, css

I've created a custom close button for a fancybox link that goes to a YouTube video. When I add a border-radius to make it a circle, the close button ends up behind the video when viewed in Firefox for some reason.

Here's the CSS:

```
.fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #CCC;
    z-index: 8040;
}
```

The full site can be viewed here
http://www.neoscapelabs.com/projects/469seventh/

Comment: displays as a circle on top the video in my chrome

Comment: same here, which browser are you testing on?

Comment: My mistake, the issue seems to only happen in Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a couple of tweaks to your code :

1). Change the URL of your link from this :

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/PzBk4-awY40?autoplay=1
```

to this

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/PzBk4-awY40?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque
```

**Notice** we switched from `v/` to `embed/` and added the trailing parameter `&wmode=opaque`

2). As odd as it sounds, set `wmode` to `opaque` to your *iframe* too. You can do that with the `iframe` API option like :

```
iframe : {
    preload: false,
    wmode: "opaque"
}
```

BTW, I would also advise you to set `preload` to `false`.

**<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnm62/)</kbd>**